# Postgres: aggregate function required when using Case and Group By but only when join is used

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm having a strange issue with one of my postgres queries. The query works fine in multiple scenarios with various other groupings, sums, etc except for one very specific scenario.

The code below is counting rows from 5 different tables (ignore the fact that this in itself is dumb, its a very bad and annoying database structure) and grouping them depending on the value returned in a CASE function. It works fine when it is as below:

```
SELECT SUM(count) as count, status FROM
(SELECT count(fsp.id) as count, CASE WHEN fsp.stageonecompletetime = 0 THEN 'in-progress'
WHEN fsp.stagetwocompletetime = 0 THEN 'awaiting-final-review'
WHEN fsp.completedtime = 0 THEN 'awaiting-authorisation'
WHEN fsp.senttodate = 0 THEN 'awaiting-distribution'
WHEN fsp.senttodate > 0 AND superseded = 0 THEN 'completed'
ELSE 'archived' END AS status FROM fleet_documents.fleet_solution_policy fsp WHERE TO_TIMESTAMP(fsp.createdtime) >= '2016-09-03' AND TO_TIMESTAMP(fsp.createdtime) < '2016-10-03' GROUP BY status
UNION ALL
SELECT count(cba.id) as count, CASE WHEN cba.stageonecompletetime = 0 THEN 'in-progress'
WHEN cba.stagetwocompletetime = 0 THEN 'awaiting-final-review'
WHEN cba.completedtime = 0 THEN 'awaiting-authorisation'
WHEN cba.senttodate = 0 THEN 'awaiting-distribution'
WHEN cba.senttodate > 0 AND superseded = 0 THEN 'completed'
ELSE 'archived' END AS status FROM fleet_documents.casing_buyback_agreement cba WHERE TO_TIMESTAMP(cba.createdtime) >= '2016-09-03' AND TO_TIMESTAMP(cba.createdtime) < '2016-10-03' GROUP BY status
UNION ALL
SELECT count(ftp.id) as count, CASE WHEN ftp.stageonecompletetime = 0 THEN 'in-progress'
WHEN ftp.stagetwocompletetime = 0 THEN 'awaiting-final-review'
WHEN ftp.completedtime = 0 THEN 'awaiting-authorisation'
WHEN ftp.senttodate = 0 THEN 'awaiting-distribution'
WHEN ftp.senttodate > 0 AND superseded = 0 THEN 'completed'
ELSE 'archived' END AS status FROM fleet_documents.fleet_tyre_policy ftp WHERE TO_TIMESTAMP(ftp.createdtime) >= '2016-09-03' AND TO_TIMESTAMP(ftp.createdtime) < '2016-10-03' GROUP BY status
UNION ALL
SELECT count(ds.id) as count, CASE WHEN ds.stageonecompletetime = 0 THEN 'in-progress'
WHEN ds.stagetwocompletetime = 0 THEN 'awaiting-final-review'
WHEN ds.completedtime = 0 THEN 'awaiting-authorisation'
WHEN ds.senttodate = 0 THEN 'awaiting-distribution'
WHEN ds.senttodate > 0 AND superseded = 0 THEN 'completed'
ELSE 'archived' END AS status FROM fleet_documents.dealer_sla ds WHERE TO_TIMESTAMP(ds.createdtime) >= '2016-09-03' AND TO_TIMESTAMP(ds.createdtime) < '2016-10-03' GROUP BY status
UNION ALL
SELECT count(cg.id) as count, CASE WHEN cg.stageonecompletetime = 0 THEN 'in-progress'
WHEN cg.stagetwocompletetime = 0 THEN 'awaiting-final-review'
WHEN cg.completedtime = 0 THEN 'awaiting-authorisation'
WHEN cg.senttodate = 0 THEN 'awaiting-distribution'
WHEN cg.senttodate > 0 AND superseded = 0 THEN 'completed'
ELSE 'archived' END AS status FROM fleet_documents.casing_grid cg WHERE TO_TIMESTAMP(cg.createdtime) >= '2016-09-03' AND TO_TIMESTAMP(cg.createdtime) < '2016-10-03' GROUP BY status) allDocuments
GROUP BY status
```

But when I have to do joins in the query to allow me to filter the results by user, as below I get an annoying error:

```
SELECT SUM(count) as count, status FROM
    (SELECT count(fsp.id) as count, CASE WHEN fsp.stageonecompletetime = 0 THEN 'in-progress'
        WHEN fsp.stagetwocompletetime = 0 THEN 'awaiting-final-review'
        WHEN fsp.completedtime = 0 THEN 'awaiting-authorisation'
        WHEN fsp.senttodate = 0 THEN 'awaiting-distribution'
        WHEN fsp.senttodate > 0 AND superseded = 0 THEN 'completed'
        ELSE 'archived' END AS status FROM fleet_documents.fleet_solution_policy fsp JOIN users u1 ON u1.id = fsp.user_id WHERE TO_TIMESTAMP(fsp.createdtime) >= '2016-09-03' AND TO_TIMESTAMP(fsp.createdtime) < '2016-10-03' AND lower(u1.username) = 'Test' GROUP BY status
    UNION ALL
    SELECT count(cba.id) as count, CASE WHEN cba.stageonecompletetime = 0 THEN 'in-progress'
        WHEN cba.stagetwocompletetime = 0 THEN 'awaiting-final-review'
        WHEN cba.completedtime = 0 THEN 'awaiting-authorisation'
        WHEN cba.senttodate = 0 THEN 'awaiting-distribution'
        WHEN cba.senttodate > 0 AND superseded = 0 THEN 'completed'
        ELSE 'archived' END AS status FROM fleet_documents.casing_buyback_agreement cba JOIN users u4 ON u4.id = cba.user_id WHERE TO_TIMESTAMP(cba.createdtime) >= '2016-09-03' AND TO_TIMESTAMP(cba.createdtime) < '2016-10-03' AND lower(u4.username) = 'Test' GROUP BY status
    UNION ALL
    SELECT count(ftp.id) as count, CASE WHEN ftp.stageonecompletetime = 0 THEN 'in-progress'
        WHEN ftp.stagetwocompletetime = 0 THEN 'awaiting-final-review'
        WHEN ftp.completedtime = 0 THEN 'awaiting-authorisation'
        WHEN ftp.senttodate = 0 THEN 'awaiting-distribution'
        WHEN ftp.senttodate > 0 AND superseded = 0 THEN 'completed'
        ELSE 'archived' END AS status FROM fleet_documents.fleet_tyre_policy ftp JOIN users u2 ON u2.id = ftp.user_id WHERE TO_TIMESTAMP(ftp.createdtime) >= '2016-09-03' AND TO_TIMESTAMP(ftp.createdtime) < '2016-10-03' AND lower(u2.username) = 'Test' GROUP BY status
    UNION ALL
    SELECT count(ds.id) as count, CASE WHEN ds.stageonecompletetime = 0 THEN 'in-progress'
        WHEN ds.stagetwocompletetime = 0 THEN 'awaiting-final-review'
        WHEN ds.completedtime = 0 THEN 'awaiting-authorisation'
        WHEN ds.senttodate = 0 THEN 'awaiting-distribution'
        WHEN ds.senttodate > 0 AND superseded = 0 THEN 'completed'
        ELSE 'archived' END AS status FROM fleet_documents.dealer_sla ds JOIN users u3 ON u3.id = ds.user_id WHERE TO_TIMESTAMP(ds.createdtime) >= '2016-09-03' AND TO_TIMESTAMP(ds.createdtime) < '2016-10-03' AND lower(u3.username) = 'Test' GROUP BY status
    UNION ALL
    SELECT count(cg.id) as count, CASE WHEN cg.stageonecompletetime = 0 THEN 'in-progress'
        WHEN cg.stagetwocompletetime = 0 THEN 'awaiting-final-review'
        WHEN cg.completedtime = 0 THEN 'awaiting-authorisation'
        WHEN cg.senttodate = 0 THEN 'awaiting-distribution'
        WHEN cg.senttodate > 0 AND superseded = 0 THEN 'completed'
        ELSE 'archived' END AS status FROM fleet_documents.casing_grid cg JOIN users u5 ON u5.id = cg.user_id WHERE TO_TIMESTAMP(cg.createdtime) >= '2016-09-03' AND TO_TIMESTAMP(cg.createdtime) < '2016-10-03' AND lower(u5.username) = 'Test' GROUP BY status) allDocuments
GROUP BY status
```

The error I get is as follows: ERROR:  column "fsp.stageonecompletetime" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function.

Now, I can't understand why I am getting this error returned only when I do the join with the user table.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not sure if it will be helpful, because I work in Oracle SQL environment, but there you can not just put status into the group by, you have to pust the whole case when clause. Have you tried that?

Comment: Can you explain what `TO_TIMESTAMP` does here? Are the createdtime stored as string? If so, in what format? And doesn't `lower(username) = 'Test'` look funny?

Comment: Hey, yea, the 'Test' was my mistake (As I changed the actual username when submitting this question) and I forgot it was lower.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that your users table has a column named status in it, and this has changed the semantics of the group by so it no longer references the aliased case expression.

Try changing the alias you are using.

Comment: Thanks, I believe this might have been the issue as I do have a status column in the users table. I ultimately ended up fixing it in a different way, by taking out the aggregate functions and groupings in the subquery, instead returning every row as it is, and then only doing the aggregates and grouping in the main query.

Comment: @David Aldridge: This seems very likely. Also this shows that one better not uses alias in `GROUP BY` at all, for if you use the alias `state` instead of `status` now, the query will only run as long as nobody adds a column `state` to one of the tables :-) If using an alias at all, one should use some naming convention so as to avoid having the same name for an alias and a column.

Comment: @bigad1992: That sounds good. When using all tables the same, one can simply union-all them and work on the whole.

Answer (score 1):

This is no real answer. The correct answer has already been given by David Aldridge.

---

Here is how I would write the query. I wouldn't join users at all. And I would first glue all tables together and then work with them as if they were just one table. I classify the data in a subquery and use the created alias in the main query then.

```
select count(*), status
from
(
  select
    case  
      when stageonecompletetime = 0 then 'in-progress'
      when stagetwocompletetime = 0 then 'awaiting-final-review'
      when completedtime = 0 then 'awaiting-authorisation'
      when senttodate = 0 then 'awaiting-distribution'
      when senttodate > 0 and superseded = 0 then 'completed'
      else 'archived' 
    end as status 
  from 
  (
    select user_id, createdtime, stageonecompletetime, stagetwocompletetime, completedtime, senttodate, superseded from fleet_documents.fleet_solution_policy
    union all
    select user_id, createdtime, stageonecompletetime, stagetwocompletetime, completedtime, senttodate, superseded from fleet_documents.casing_buyback_agreement
    union all
    select user_id, createdtime, stageonecompletetime, stagetwocompletetime, completedtime, senttodate, superseded from fleet_documents.fleet_tyre_policy
    union all
    select user_id, createdtime, stageonecompletetime, stagetwocompletetime, completedtime, senttodate, superseded from fleet_documents.dealer_sla
    union all
    select user_id, createdtime, stageonecompletetime, stagetwocompletetime, completedtime, senttodate, superseded from fleet_documents.casing_grid
  ) data
) classified
where createdtime >= '2016-09-03' 
  and createdtime < '2016-10-03'
  and user_id in (select id from users where lower(username) = 'test')
group by status
order by count(*);
```

Only if that got too slow would I move the `WHERE` clause to the single table queries. As is the query is much more readable and maintainable.